# Finding a known height in an image

Tags: image-processing, camera

I have an image of a wall taken from a phone camera from a known height h from the ground.

Assume that the camera was held perfectly parallel to the wall and that the bottom of the image is perfectly aligned with the bottom of the wall.

Is there a way to find out the point in the image that corresponds to the height h ? 
(i.e if I drew an imaginary line (that's parallel to the ground) from the camera lens to the wall, at what point would the intersection of the line on the wall show up in the image ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some real difficulties with this.  Your camera's focal length and your device's aspect ratio will make for a wide variety of results from device to device and location to location.  Also a minute variance in your camera's alignment vertically would have a huge resultant change in the calculated height.

[image]

If your goal was to take mugshots, or some such thing with a specific camera in a fixed location, you could rig up something based on trial and error. Otherwise, I wouldn't trust it at all.

Also, [here is a link](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Lenses_and_Field_of_View) explaining focal length of field of view.  It is a complex subject.

Comment: Thanks HalR. To clarify, my goal is to calculate the wall dimensions. I'm trying to calculate the scale of the image relative to the real world using the height h.

Comment: That is what I thought you were saying.  I will draw up a diagram to show you what I mean.